# SyntaxError: bad token on line 5 in main.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, turtle

Сейчас я изучаю черепашку. Вот так звучит задача:

Напишите программу для рисования паутины в соответствии с примером. Программа должна считывать количество лучей паутины, число n.

Примечание. Угол заданный каждой парой лучей составляет 360/n градусов.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:

```
from turtle import *
dot(20)
n = int(input())
shape('triangle')
с = 360 / n
for _ in range(n):
  forward(100)
  stamp()
  backward(100)
  right(c)
```

Но он выдаёт ошибку:

```
SyntaxError: bad token on line 5 in main.py
```

Что это такое, и как это исправить?

Comment: Указанная ошибка у меня не воспроизводится, появляется ошибка `NameError: name 'c' is not defined` из-за того что у вас в одном месте `c` латинская, в другом месте - в русской раскладке. Если это исправить, то все работает.

Comment: Ну и dot лучше вызывать после input, чтобы окно черепашки рано на передний план не вылезало, и не перекрывало консоль, в которую нужно число лучей ввести.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы случайно написали русскую `c`

```
from turtle import *
dot(20)
n = int(input())
shape('triangle')
#################
c = 360 / n
#################
for _ in range(n):
  forward(100)
  stamp()
  backward(100)
  right(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

в конце я бы добавил mainloop() чтобы окно с паутинкой не закрывалось автоматически по завершению цикла

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).